# Dell PERC H710P 8 drives show up in 4 pairs with same id

Tags: raid, sas

I’ve scoured the Dell documentation for the product, but I can’t for the life of me figure out what I might be doing wrong.

I have 8 4TB HGST SAS drives in an enclosure. The Perc bios will only let me configure a raid with half the capacity I should have. Configuring the raid looks like this:
 [image: Drives listed in bios]

As you can see it seems to be detecting it as if it were two duplicate enclosures of four drives a piece. I tried to just suck it up and make two virtual disks, but I can’t.

Does anyone here have experience with a PERC H710P and can possibly shed some light? I’m out of ideas.